# Subsets $Y$ of a partially ordered set $L$ need not have least upper bounds nor greatest lower bounds

Tags: real-analysis, order-theory, upper-lower-bounds

I am currently studying the textbook *Principles of Program Analysis* by Flemming Nielson, Hanne R. Nielson, and Chris Hankin. **Appendix A Partially Ordered Sets** says the following:

> **Partially ordered set.** A *partial ordering* is a relation $\sqsubseteq : L \times L \rightarrow \{ \text{true}, \text{false} \}$ that is reflexive (i.e. $\forall l : l \sqsubseteq l$), transitive (i.e. $\forall l_1, l_2, l_3 : l_1 \sqsubseteq l_2 \land l_2 \sqsubseteq l_3 \Rightarrow l_1 \sqsubseteq l_3$), and anti-symmetric (i.e. $\forall l_1, l_2 : l_1 \sqsubseteq l_2 \land l_2 \sqsubseteq l_1 \Rightarrow l_1 = l_2$). A *partially ordered set* $(L, \sqsubseteq)$ is a set $L$ equipped with a partial ordering $\sqsubseteq$ (sometimes written $\sqsubseteq_L$). We shall write $l_2 \sqsupseteq l_1$ for $l_1 \sqsubseteq l_2$ and $l_1 \sqsubset l_2$ for $l_1 \sqsubseteq l_2 \land l_1 \not= l_2$.
>
> A subset $Y$ of $L$ has $l \in L$ as an *upper bound* if $\forall l^\prime \in Y : l^\prime \sqsubseteq l$ and as a *lower bound* if $\forall l^\prime \in Y : l^\prime \sqsupseteq l$. A *least upper bound* $l$ of $Y$ is an upper bound of $Y$ that satisfies $l \sqsubseteq l_0$ whenever $l_0$ is another upper bound of $Y$; similarly, a *greatest lower bound* $l$ of $Y$ is a lower bound of $Y$ that satisfies $l_0 \sqsubseteq l$ whenever $l_0$ is another lower bound of $Y$. Note that subsets $Y$ of a partially ordered set $L$ need not have least upper bounds nor greatest lower bounds but when they exist they are unique (since $\sqsubseteq$ is anti-symmetric) and they are denoted $\bigsqcup Y$ and $\sqcap Y$, respectively.

It is this part that I am unsure about:

> Note that subsets $Y$ of a partially ordered set $L$ need not have least upper bounds nor greatest lower bounds but when they exist they are unique (since $\sqsubseteq$ is anti-symmetric) and they are denoted $\bigsqcup Y$ and $\sqcap Y$, respectively.

This isn't obvious to me. Would someone please explain/clarify this?

Comment: Consider $(0, \infty) \subseteq \mathbb{R}$, which has no upper bound, and $(-\infty, 0)$, which has no lower bound. Also consider the signed integers $\mathbb{Z} \subseteq \mathbb{R}$, which has neither.

Comment: Consider the set $\{1,2,3,12,18,72,108,216\}$ ordered by the relation "$x$ divides $y$". The set $\{12,18\}$ has no least upper bound and no greatest lower bound.

Comment: Also, if $X$ is a set with two elements or more, then $(X,=)$ is a poset where for two different elements $a,b$ there is neither their glb not their lub (it's called an anti-chain).

Comment: @BrianO This is the only response that has been informative.

Comment: @bof you’ll have to explain this further, since it isn’t clear to me how the set has no least upper bound and no greatest lower bound.

Comment: @ ThePointer Thanks, glad you found the examples useful. Note, the comment by @amrsa is correct: $=$ is "trivially" antisymmetric, because for all $x, y \in X$, if $x = y$ and $y = x$ then surely $x = y$.

Comment: @BrianO Oh, ok. Thanks for the clarification. Is my comment to rpl19's answer correct?

Comment: @ThePointer Regrettably, no, it isn't :) (See my reply.)

Answer (score 0):

To see that there are posets without least upper bounds nor greatest lower bounds consider $L = [-1,0) \cup (0,1) \cup (1,2]$ and $Y = (0,1)$. Let your partial order be the usual total order on $\mathbb{R}$. Then there is no least upper bound or greatest lower bound of $Y$ in $L$.

To prove this explicitly for the least upper bound case: suppose some $l \in L$ were a least upper bound of $Y$. Then we can select any $l_0 \in (1,l)$ and $l_0 < l$ is another upper bound for $Y$, but it's less than $l$. This is a contradiction, so no least upper bound can exist.

A similar argument works for the greatest lower bound.

For the uniqueness aspect, given existence, suppose both $l$ and $l^\prime$ were a least upper bound for $Y$ in $L$. Then this means in particular that they are both an upper bound. So $l \sqsubseteq l^\prime$ because $l$ is a least upper bound. But, $l^\prime \sqsubseteq l$ since $l'$ is also a least upper bound. By anti-symmetry this means we must have $l = l^\prime$.

A similar argument works for uniqueness of a greatest lower bound given its existence.

Comment: $<$ is not anti-symmetric, and therefore it is not a POSET.

Comment: @ThePointer $<$ is the strict version of the usual $\le$ relation on reals, which of course *is* a partial order, as is its restriction to the answer's set $L$. This set is just $[-1, 2]$ with the points $0$ and $1$ removed. It should be clear that its subset $(0, 1)$ has no lub and no glb, though it's bounded above and below in $L$.

Comment: @ThePointer As BrianO pointed out, this is a poset. The difference between a partial order and a total order is convexity. That is, total orders are indeed anti-symmetric (and have all the other properties of a partial order), and have the additional property that you can compare any two elements. The example I gave is taking the closed set $[-1,2]$ with this partial order and removing two points that would be the upper and lower bounds of the subset $(0,1)$. Please let me know if my answer is still unclear.

Comment: Thanks again for the clarification. I don't understand this one. If we have $L = [-1,0) \cup (0,1) \cup (1,2]$ and $Y = (0,1)$, then how do we reason about the least upper bound and greatest lower bound? Furthermore, I don't understand why the answer is switching between $<$ and $\sqsubseteq$.

Comment: @BrianO Do you want to post a clearer answer for the bounty, by any chance?

Comment: @ThePointer It's not clear what I could clarify further, but time permitting I'll attempt it.

Comment: @BrianO Great, thanks. Just an answer that gives a clear example and clearly explains it (for instance, an elaboration of your comment to the main post). The example given by this answer is just unclear to me.